I get a TypeError exception while using winappdriver with selenium
I'm new to this whole automation thing with WinAppDriver and Selenium, and I keep getting a
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'

exception when I try to pass in the desired capabilities. Maybe I just don't understand this. This is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# Set up desired capabilities
desired_capabilities = {
    "app": "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
}

# Initialize the WebDriver with WinAppDriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities
)

try:
    # Wait for the app to open
    time.sleep(5)

    # Perform a simple calculation: 7 + 3 = 10
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Seven").click()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Plus").click()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Three").click()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Equals").click()

    # Wait to see the result
    time.sleep(2)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    # Close the application and quit the driver
    driver.quit()


and I get the following traceback:
File "C:\Users\Dell\GuiAuto", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'

I tried looking into tutorials and the web but I still don't know what went wrong, really.

Welcome to SO! Seeing as you're getting an error on line 11, the vast majority of this code is irrelevant to your question. Consider removing it with an [edit] so your code better resembles an [mre].

Also, can someone who's smarter than me explain what it means to open the Windows calculator with Selenium?

Also, desired_capabilities is legacy code. You'll need to use options instead, unless you want to use an old version of Selenium. You can find the documentation here.
